# json parsing error. what's wrong?

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

What is wrong with the syntax? I tried the same syntax on the highcharts demo and it works. but json didn't parse it properly and throwing syntax error. Please help

http://jsfiddle.net/gQ9M7/2/
Below string is for illustration of dynamic data....

```
var datax="{\"name\":\"Tokyo\",\"data\":[[\"test\",7.0],[\"test2\",6.9]]},{\"name\":\"New York\",\"data\":[[\"test\",5.0],[\"test2\",8.9]]}";

$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [$.parseJSON(datax)]
        });
    });
```

Comment: The string is simulating a dynamic case and is given for illustration purposes. It has to be a string. I also tried wrapping in [] without luck... http://jsfiddle.net/gQ9M7/4/ (it ignores the data but no syntax error this time) any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with parsing a string? Just make datax a real object literal and pass it to series. Also, your JSON is invalid, looks like the whole thing should be wrapped in `[]` to make it an array.

```
var datax=[{"name":"Tokyo","data":[["test",7.0],["test2",6.9]]},{"name":"New York","data":[["test",5.0],["test2",8.9]]}];

// snip

    series: datax
});
```

Working fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/gQ9M7/3/

#### Update

If it **must** be a string, use better quotes to avoid all the escaping and don't wrap the parsed object in an array, eg

```
var datax='[{"name":"Tokyo","data":[["test",7.0],["test2",6.9]]},{"name":"New York","data":[["test",5.0],["test2",8.9]]}]';

// snip

series: $.parseJSON(datax)
```

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/gQ9M7/5/